# Is there any way to programmatically detect if setting "Random hardware addresses" is enabled?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, networking, wifi

I am trying to detect if the setting called "Random hardware addresses" is enabled on a Windows machine.

I would like to filter out network cards that have this option enabled and only leave network cards that have this option disabled. I am trying to code this for c++, but i can also accept c#.
I can also work with just a global feedback that this is enabled in general on a Windows machine.

So far i have searched through the register at the best of my abilities and though iptypes.h.
Did not find any interface that would provide this information.

EDIT:
I need a MAC list that does not contain cards with this option enabled.
Currently i am using GetAdaptersInfo() and RegQueryValueEx() to query all cards and get other information of network interfaces.

Comment: I'm more curious about why you need this? What is the actual and underlying problem this is supposed to solve? Please ask about it directly instead.

Comment: Remember that is only for Wi-Fi, not ethernet. Also, for random MAC addressing, the U/L flag will be set, but that is not a guarantee it is a random MAC address because there are other reasons it may be set.

Comment: Very interesting @RonMaupin! I will check this out. Linking wiki page for others: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Universal_vs._local_(U/L_bit)